# searching a concatenated string in whole database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a concatenated string in Whole Oracle Database Using Below Script

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
-- Type the owner of the tables you are looking at
--  v_owner VARCHAR2(255) :='APEX_030200';

-- Type the data type you are look at (in CAPITAL)
-- VARCHAR2, NUMBER, etc.
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(255) :='VARCHAR2';

-- Type the string you are looking at
  v_search_string VARCHAR2(4000) :='48-S-9-00028';

  v_sql varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (
    SELECT table_name, column_name,owner 
    FROM sys.all_tab_cols 
    WHERE 
      data_type LIKE '%CHAR%' 
      AND owner NOT IN ('XDB','SYS','SYSMAN') 
      AND table_name <> 'Folder36_TAB'
  ) LOOP

    --v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| t.owner || '.'||t.table_name||' WHERE '||t.column_name || ' like ''%'' || :1 || ''%''';
    v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| t.owner || '.'||t.table_name||' WHERE '||t.column_name || ' =  :1 ';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    v_sql
    INTO match_count
    USING v_search_string;

    IF match_count > 0 THEN
       dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
      dbms_output.put_line(t.owner||'.'|| t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
END;
/
```

The String `48-S-9-00028` is concatenation of 4 Columns 
like `48` , `S` , `9` AND `00028` = `48-S-9-00028`

I want to find the concatenated string through whole database that which 4 columns are making this string , I have tried from below scripts but its only giving output for a single value.

Comment: What are the names of the 4 columns that you want to search ? Do the columns to search are the same in all tables ?

Comment: not sure , if i know i must go to those columns and find the values

Comment: database is too big and i can't check one by one

Comment: so basically any combination of 4 columns in any table could match the 4 values given as input ?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This looks like a complex requirement. What if a table has 50 columns ? That's a LOT of possible 4-columns combinations...

Comment: So any alternate way to find this string `48-S-9-00028` really i am stuck

Comment: First question is why are you trying to search your database like this? Shouldn't you know which columns are being concatenated to make this string?

Comment: No i don't as this is a new client for and client have just shown me a report for which we dont have source code , so exactly dont know which 4 columns are being concatenated

Comment: The very small example HR database has 54 columns in it, which leads to 316,000 possible combinations of columns. Consider that these values might not be from the same table and row and you basically have an infinite possible number of combinations. Your best bet is probably to take what you know about this report and reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: Exactly how many database tables are we talking here?

Comment: 845 Total Columns with %CHAR% data Type

Comment: Ask your DBA to switch on tracing/monitoring for the session that runs the report. This should enable him/her to grab the SQL trace file which will contain the queries being run. Search through this file and hopefully you should find the one you are after. Alternatively, the DBA might be able to get this retrospectively if they have AWR or similar tools.

Comment: *"845 Total Columns with %CHAR% data Type"* - both `48` and `9` could come from numeric columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value being searched is from 4 concatenated cols, then your best bet doing a trawl is to search for each component value, since the value `'48-S-9-00028'` won't actually exist.

If the the values is obtained from a view with derived values, then you'll be out of luck. All is not lost though, see my comment about using AWR or trace to find what queries are being run.

So, searching for this I would change your trawl to the following (NOTE, this is functional only, might not be quick):

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
  match_value VARCHAR2(20);
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(255) :='VARCHAR2';
  v_sql varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (
    SELECT table_name, column_name,owner 
    FROM sys.all_tab_cols 
    WHERE 
      data_type LIKE '%CHAR%' 
      AND owner NOT IN ('XDB','SYS','SYSMAN') 
      AND table_name <> 'Folder36_TAB'
  ) LOOP

      v_sql := 'SELECT ''' || t.column_name || ''' cn '
                 'FROM '|| t.owner || '.'||t.table_name||
                 ' WHERE '||t.column_name || ' IN ( ''48'', ''S'', ''9'', ''00028'' ) ' ||
                 ' AND rownum < 2';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO match_value;

      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
      dbms_output.put_line(t.owner||'.'|| t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_value );
   END IF;
END;
```

That is, search for any table where any of the 4 component values exist, return just the value matched and just the first row found to help you narrow your search.

Comment: Idea is great let me check it and let you know however i was trying like this ` select v.SQL_TEXT,
           v.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
           v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,
           v.DISK_READS,
           v.ROWS_PROCESSED,
           v.ELAPSED_TIME,
           v.service
      from v$sql v
where to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate)
and PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = 'APPS'
AND UPPER(v.SQL_TEXT) LIKE 'SELECT%'
ORDER BY to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') DESC`

Comment: Search `v$sql_text` for the full query. Get a rough idea of the time of the report and restrict the date/time window in your query to that.

Comment: Look at the generated sql (v_sql) .. does it query all the tables you expect it to? Also, try `ROWNUM = 1` instead of `< 2`.

Comment: client is running the report , how can i check the last executed sql in database .. if  i can check i will find the query

Comment: If you have SQL Developer you can use the Tools/Monitor option to search/select the session and enable trace. Or, identify the session from `v$session` then use `exec sys.dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session(SID,SERIAL, TRUE)`. More info here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:497421739750 .

Comment: Another thought, what format is the report program that i running? Can you try running `strings -a report_program` ... if the queries are in string/text fields you might be able to see them. I think this works with Oracle Reports files as well.

Comment: An up vote or tick would be nice if my help was useful. Speaking of which, what part exactly helped you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> " client have just shown me a report for which we dont have source code , so exactly dont know which 4 columns are being concatenated"

First of all, the client must have some idea of what data this report presents. This could give you some clue to what sort of tables you need to look at.

Secondly, if it's a business key - and if it isn't then why look for it - then just maybe there's a primary key or unique key defined for those columns. So, this query might produce some candidates:

```
 select c.constraint_name, c.constraint_type 
 from user_cons_columns cc
      join user_constraints c
           on c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
 group by c.constraint_name, c.constraint_type having count(cc.column_name) = 4;
```

Both these suggests assume a sensible naming convention and proper enforcement of relational integrity. Under the circumstances you might not be that lucky.

In which case, enable SQL Trace, run the report then peruse the trace file to see all the queries which provide the data. Your table will be one of those. [Find out more.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof)